# How to set order in Elasticsearch sortion

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to apply order for sorting in Elasticsearch. Unfortunately, common standard sort can't sort in next way:

1. special chars
2. numbers
3. alphabetic(aA-zZ)

My mapping:

```json
PUT /sorting_by_name
{
  "mappings": {
    "sorting_by_name": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am querying Elasticsearch as follows:

```json
GET /sorting_by_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": [
    { "name": { "order": "asc" } }
  ]
}
```

And I would want to get the following result:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "AXe1Y7vv7OkJxgqzrpj9",
    "_source": {
      "name": "{{{{ A {{{ sdasd"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "AXe1Y7vv7OkJxgqzrpj9",
    "_source": {
      "name": "{{{{ A {{{ sdasd"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "AXe1QBZz7OkJxgqzrpj2",
    "_source": {
      "name": "11asdasd"
    }
  }
              {
    "_id": "AXe1Y6id7OkJxgqzrpj8",
    "_source": {
      "name": "A {{{ sdasd"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "AXe1QFwn7OkJxgqzrpj4",
    "_source": {
      "name": "asdasd"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "AXe1ZOGe7OkJxgqzrpkC",
    "_source": {
      "name": "Ooopopl"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "AXe1ZM4V7OkJxgqzrpkB",
    "_source": {
      "name": "ooopopl"
    }
  }
]
```

But now I get the following result:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "AXe1Y7vv7OkJxgqzrpj9",
    "_source": {
      "name": "{{{{ A {{{ sdasd"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "AXe1QBZz7OkJxgqzrpj2",
    "_source": {
      "name": "11asdasd"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "AXe1Y6id7OkJxgqzrpj8",
    "_source": {
      "name": "A {{{ sdasd"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "AXe1ZOGe7OkJxgqzrpkC",
    "_source": {
      "name": "Ooopopl"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "AXe1QFwn7OkJxgqzrpj4",
    "_source": {
      "name": "asdasd"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "AXe1ZM4V7OkJxgqzrpkB",
    "_source": {
      "name": "ooopopl"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "AXe1Y7vv7OkJxgqzrpj9",
    "_source": {
      "name": "{{{{ A {{{ sdasd"
    }
  }
]
```

How would I get the expected result?

Comment: the closest I can get is 1. numbers 2. alphabetic 3. special chars. I achieve this by applying `lowercase` filter to the property mapping

Comment: @BohdanStupak ok, I will check it.